# How to concat property values in ember template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to ember.
I am facing a problem while building a dynamic string for ember-social url.

```
{{facebook-share tagName='a' url='http://my.domain.com/details?articleid={{article.id}}' }}
```

The article.id does not get resolved 
What is correct way of using the nested handlebar items?

Thanks in advance!!
Cheers 
Amit

Answer (score 4):

there is [concat](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_concat) helper that you could use

```
{{facebook-share tagName='a' url=(concat 'http://my.domain.com/details?articleid=' article.id) }}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works kool :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a computed property for that:

```
articleUrl: Ember.computed('article.id', function(){
   return 'http://my.domain.com/details?articleid=' + this.get('article.id');
});
```

and then, in your handlebar:

```
{{facebook-share tagName='a' url=articleUrl}}
```

Comment: Thank you :). Does help to handle even more complicated stuff in future.